# utf8mb4 characters lost in export/import in Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, utf8mb4, sequelpro

I'm using the Encoding `UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)` and Collation `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` for both tables and fields in my MySQL database.

When I export the database from Sequel Pro and open the exported .sql file in a text editor my test character  appears correctly, but when I import the file back into Sequel Pro it appears as `????` both in Sequel Pro and in my PHP/MySQL app.

In the import window I've tried `Autodetect` and `Unicode (UTF-8)` without success. Any ideas?

Also, is there any newer encoding out there that I should use instead () and is there any benefit of using `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` instead of just `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`?

Edit / Here's a picture of what I'm trying to do. It seems like my "odd" character is on track all the way until I'm trying to import the .sql file back into Sequel PRO.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `COLLATION` does not matter except for ordering.  The `CHARACTER SET` does matter, since this is a 4-byte code.

Somehow `CHARACTER SET utf8` got involved, in spite of what you say.  See "question marks" in [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for the likely causes.

Do `SELECT HEX(...) ...` to verify that that character was actually stored as hex `F09D8C86`.

Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can verify that the *column* is utf8mb4.

And, let's see the connection parameters.

Comment: Thanks Rick! I checked and the hex returns `F09D8C86` before I export it out of Sequel PRO, but when I import it again it returns `3F3F3F3F` (?????). `SHOW CREATE TABLE` returns `utf8mb4` before export and after import. Have I missed any settings in Sequel PRO?

Comment: What about the character set setting?  `SET NAMES utf8mb4` (or equivalent) is needed to announce that the client has 4-byte UTF-8 characters.

Comment: do you know how I do that in Sequel PRO? Everything is working in my php/mysql web app, and in Sequel PRO... until I make a backup/export in S PRO and import it again. I get the ????

Comment: Check there various items in "Best practice" in my link.  I don't know Sequel PRO.  I your image, I see nothing about the _connection_ during the Import.

Comment: It seems to be a Sequel PRO thing. I've asked in their forum. Thank you!

Comment: Found out that Sequel PRO can not export utf8mb4 yet, but will be able to in v1.2!

Comment: (`<snarky>`I spend too much time chasing deficiencies in 3rd-party packages that get in the way of using MySQL.`</snarky>`)